# How many minutes does it take $n$ moles to dig $m$ holes.

Tags: logic

Recently, I came across this problem:

> 5 moles dig 4 holes in 3 minutes. How many minutes will it take 9 moles to dig 6 holes?

I decided that I should just use proportions and calculate it.

$\implies 5$ moles dig 1 hole in $\frac{3}{4}$ minutes.

$\implies 9$ moles dig $\frac{9}{5}$ holes in $\frac{27}{20}$ minutes.

I quickly realize that this won't work, because the proportions asked are not the same.

However, I can't think of any other way to calculate this.

I figured that this question can be in the form

> If $n$ objects do $m$ things in $o$ time units, how many time units can $x$ objects do $y$ things?

How can I solve this type of problem?

Thanks for your help! Your help is appreciated!

Max0815

Comment: Hint: 4 holes take 15 mole minutes.

Comment: You technically need to know that this is some sort of linear relationship too I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start with $x=3 \ (\text{minutes})\cdot \ldots$, where 3 is the number you start from. And $x$ is the time  to dig 6 holes by 9 moles. Then build a fraction of the following pairs of numbers: $(5,9);(6,4)$

The more moles are digging the less time is needed. Thus the fraction has to be smaller than 1. That means the factor is $\frac59$.

The more holes  supposed to be dug the more time is needed. Thus the fraction has to be greater than 1. That means the factor is $\frac64$.

Thus $x=3\cdot \frac59\cdot \frac64=2.5 \ (\text{minutes})$

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track.  You are expected to compute how many mole-minutes it takes to dig one hole.  Then given any number of holes, you know how many mole-minutes are required, so divide by the number of moles.

Comment: Would I do as @Mark Bennet hinted 3 times 15 then divide by $\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: I don't understand the calculation you are suggesting.  I don't see where $3$ or $\frac 32$ come into it.  He and I are suggesting the same thing.

Comment: @Max0815 Just to confirm that Ross and I are suggesting the same. The trip hazard here is that we can become used to thinking about the rates at which things happen in quantities per minute, and are tempted to divide when we shouldn't. If you get into your head the idea of the "mole-minute", which implies multiplication rather than division, you will see that the number of mole-minutes is the capacity for digging holes. Units like "man-days" arise in similar problems.

Comment: @Mark Bennet I understand

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to questions of this sort is to assume that a particular animal (or person) performs a certain task at a constant rate. In this problem we suppose all moles are the same, so doubling the number of moles will double the number of holes in a given length of time;
doubling the time without changing the number of moles also will double the number of holes; but doubling the time *and* doubling the number of moles will cause them to dig *four times* as many holes.

You made a mistake by multiplying all three numbers by $\frac95.$ As shown in the examples above, the three numbers do not all go up or down in proportion.

The things that *do* go up or down proportionally are the number of holes and the product of the number of moles and the time:

$$ holes = constant \times moles \times minutes .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to see why your logic does not work:

Suppose 1 mole digs 1 hole in 1 minute

Then by your logic, it would follow that:

2 moles dig 2 holes in 2 minutes

But that's absurd: The 2 moles get twice as much done as 1 mole in the same time period, and so the 2 moles will dig 2 holes still in that same 1 minute.